# In what kind of system, relativistic effect is non-negligible?

Tags: electronic-structure

For electron with large kinetic energy, one needs to introduce Dirac equation for relativistic correction. In what type of systems these relativistic effects is non-negligible?

Comment: The answer depends on the property you want to calculate. For example, if you study spin-orbit coupling, you have to somehow deal with relativistic effects. Also note, that there are many kinds of corrections to treat relativistic effects.

Comment: I would be appreciated if you could recommend me some literature on the topic of spin-orbit coupling.